# How we are directly using setContentView inside onCreate method which is Override method in main activity?

Tags: java, android, setcontentview

in java, inheritance  works like following
..

```
public class Test1 extends Test{
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test1 test1=new Test1();
        System.out.println(test1.getName());

    }
}



public class Test{
    String name = "Happy";
    int id=64;
  
    public String getName(){
     
        return name;
    };
  
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

}
```

---

but in android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "androiod";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

how setContentView is used in android .its  declared in its parent class as onCreate is defined in its main class. onCreate and setContentView are methods of the same class(referring to Appcompactactivity class).  **on create is overridden, I understand**. but how setContentView is used directly. I mean if it's inherited from appCompact.. class ..  in a child we can override parent class methods as we did to onCreate... but how setContentView is used directly neither we are overriding nor we are creating any object of Main activity class

Comment: In java, you can override some methods while not overriding other methods. There is nothing unusual.

Comment: Overriding is required when you want to change the behaviour of a Parent Class element from the Child Class. In this case, we're merely using the `setContentView` to use it's functionality i.e. to set the view for the activity and in this case it is accessible to the child class by default due to inheritance